# All centers coincide on K-Means clustering

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, type-conversion, k-means

I am trying to apply K-Means through the following code-snippet in Python. Basically, the `arr` is a numpy array having values in three columns ([Data with Multiple Features](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html) that I want to cluster). Here, I have used the following values: `cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS = 1.0`, `cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER = 10` and `attempts = 10`. (as per the default values in the OpenCV documnetation link above).

To be specific, my three column `arr` is a RGB image, that is reshaped such that each column represents a color channel.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

Z = np.float32(arr)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(Z, 4, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
labelToUse = (label.flatten()).astype('int32')
centerToUse = center.astype('float64')
```

**While this gives me perfect results 70% of the time, but in 30% of the time I'm experiencing a weird case**, as in the picture below (left one is `centerToUse`, right one is `labelToUse`). That is, all my cluster centers are (0, 0, 0), while labels are 0 for all the data points, except the last three (3, 2 and 1 respectively). Also, for the same `arr`, in some runs this abnormal case arises while in others, the results are just perfect.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me, about what should be my approach to eliminate this abnormality. I want to get decent results from K-Means each time, and not wait for good fortune. Also (don't know though whether this is relevant or not here), the situation is same in the [scikit-learn representation of K-Means](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). This improves a bit if I increase `n_init` and `max_iter` to 30 and 300 respectively, but still persists. K-Means++ initialization also does not help.

**EDIT:** Based on the comment of @dhanushka, I recorded the compactness value on using cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS. It came as follows (picture below), i.e. compactness = 61555894.92789865 when the output is perfect, while compactness = 0.0 for the 'weird' case (all centers at (0,0,0)). Possible that it exceeds the limit for the data-type.

[image]

Any leads in this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try a different center initialization algorithm, like pp-centers and see if you get a similar behavior. Also, check the compactness value returned by the function in all cases.

Comment: @dhanushka I tried it after your comment. Using cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS (K-Means++ initialization) made the situation a bit worse. The 'weird' case became more frequent. Also, I noted down the compactness value. compactness = 61555894.92789865 when the output is perfect, while compactness = 0.0 for the 'weird' case (all centers at (0,0,0)).

Comment: How is this possible? Shouldn't the compactness value be much higher in the 'weird' case? Because all centers are at (0,0,0), while RGB values range from (0,0,0) to (255,255,255).

Comment: @dhanushka I am suspecting that my compactness value becomes so large, that it exceeds the data-type limits, and is wrapped around to 0.0. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Do you see visually that it is the segmentation you want when you get this high compactness value? Maybe you can add your image here so someone can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me every time:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

arr=cv2.imread('F:/ImagesForTest/lena.jpg')
Z = np.float32(arr)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1)
ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(Z, 4, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
labelToUse = (label.flatten()).astype('uint8')
centerToUse = center.astype('float64')
print(ret)
print(labelToUse)
print(centerToUse)
```

output is always looks like this:

```
746189834.28125
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[[111.20652008 134.6521759  228.45652771 ...  76.47826385  51.76087189
  126.43478394]
 [ 62.84615707  27.25000191  92.94231415 ...  76.61538696  51.42308044
  130.98077393]
 [ 78.15841675  65.23762512 168.42573547 ... 122.78217316 136.54455566
  209.80197144]
 [ 78.06511688  57.17674255 149.40930176 ... 133.32092285 150.96278381
  207.73487854]]
```